# Nginx as reverse proxy for https traffic

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy in an environment where clients connects to my server (https://myserver:10443). I am trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy so that client will connect to Nginx proxy and Nginx will forward all requests to backend server. The communication is ssl communication on port 10443. I have installed and configured Nginx but still not able to connect to server through proxy. The configuration is

```
http
{
   server
   {
    listen 10443;
    ssl on;

     access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-error.log;

     location /
     {
        #chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass https://MYSERVER:10443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        #proxy_redirect off;
        #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
     }

     ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
     ssl_session_timeout 10m;
     keepalive_timeout 60;
     ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
     ssl_ciphers    HIGH:!aNULL:!aNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
     ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/certs/endpoint/nginx.cer;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/endpoint/nginx_d.key;

     #ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/endpoint/nginx.cer;
     #ssl_verify_client off;
     #ssl_verify_depth 2;

   }
}
```

Not sure what I have done wrong.

Comment: `proxy_pass https://MYSERVER:10443;` so your backend also speaks https on port 10443?

Comment: eventually not as proxy is inside so communication is secure. But as of now for POC purpose, it will be speaking on https on port 10443